# How to provide tls cert in Influxdb C#

Tags: c#, linux, ssl, influxdb

I use nuget library for both version

1. for **InfluxDB v2.0+**: `InfluxDB.CLient`
2. for **InfluxDB v1.7 and below**: `AdysTech.InfluxDB.Client.Net.Core`

I have the `cacert.pem`, `client.crt`, and `client.key`

what confuses me,

1. when running the `influxd`

```
influxd --tls-cert="sslcert/client.crt" --tls-key="sslcert/client.key"
```

where should the cacert.pem go?

2. in **Influxdb v2.0+**, I found the `InfluxDBClientOptions.Builder` option for `ClientCertificates`

so I create the X509Cert and set it using the builder

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2("/path/to/client.pem");
X509Certificate2Collection certs = new();
certs.Add(cert);

var options = new InfluxDBClientOptions.Builder()
            .ClientCertificates(certs);
```

`/path/to/client.pem` contain both the client cert and key

but then again, where do the `cacert.pem` go?

3. in **Influxdb v1.7 and below**, I found nothing from the library where i could set any tls cert. Do the library support one? or does it mean if i use the library, user cant set the cert from my program?